# How do I prevent a click handler being triggered when a child element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, events

I have two div tags, first div is the father and the second div is son Inside the father like this

```
<div id="father"> 
<div id="son"> </div>
</div>
```

And I've added an event (onclick) in div father like this

```
<div id="father" onclick="closeFather()"> 
<div id="son"> </div>
</div>
```

**My question** is why the son inherits the father in the event.

I want when I click on the Father div implement the event, but when i click on the son does not implement anything because it does not have any event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the event as one of the arguments in the `closeFather` function, then check whether the event target is the father element. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/GrKYq/9/)

```
function closeFather(e) {
    if(e.target == document.getElementById('father')) {
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

Then in the HTML you just need to add the event argument to the javascript function.

```
<div id="father" onclick="closeFather(event)">
<div id="son"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect and does not work. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/GrKYq/)

Comment: Strange. What browser are you using? I tested this one quickly and it worked fine in Chrome. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/GrKYq/9/)

Comment: @Connell Watkins - But not practically

Comment: How do you mean? I take it you have more code than just this. Do you have any other divs inside the father that you actually want to inherit the event? If you just want the event not to fire if the son is clicked, you could use `if(e.target != document.getElementById('son'))` instead.

Comment: @Connell Watkins - this code work with modern browsers but ie7,ie6 not work

Comment: I think IE uses e.srcElement rather than e.target. Try `if((e.target || e.srcElement) == document.getElementById('father'))` instead.

Answer (score 10):

This is caused by a JavaScript trait called [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). By default, your events will 'bubble up' into the DOM.

When clicking a child node, you would automatically trigger a click event for it's parent node(s).

By default, when clicking an element, **bubbling happens from the inside out**: this means that first the child element's `click()` event will be trigged, then it's parent, etc.

You can **solve the problem** by adding a secondary click handler to your child element as well and telling the browser to stop bubbling in a cross-browser compatible way like so ([see live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/emLhv/)):

```
<script language="javascript">
    function parentHandler(e) {
        alert('parent clicked');
    };

    function childHandler(e) {
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();    

        alert('child clicked');

    };    
</script>

<div id="parent" onclick="parentHandler(event);">
    Foo
    <div id="child" onclick="childHandler(event)">
        Bar
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem still exists in your example

Comment: Knowing that events bubble from the inside out is important! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It's event bubbling. Core part of DOM Events. You could `return false` and prevent bubbling in your handler (`closeFather`, but you should pass event to it) if event triggered by `son`.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to disable events!

```
.parent-element .element{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

This CSS property, when set to "none" allows elements to not receive hover/click events, instead the event will occur on anything behind it.

https://caniuse.com/?search=pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, I got around that same issue by calling both the: event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() on the child element and the bubbling behaviour was gone!. Hope it helps.