# when i click on a sub<li> of another <li> (both have onclick event liestener) i get the javascript code runnig for both of them

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I prevent a click handler being triggered when a child element is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203042/how-do-i-prevent-a-click-handler-being-triggered-when-a-child-element-is-clicked)

```
<ul>
  <li>UNIT 1 - Description of unit
    <ul>
      <li id="0" onclick="alert(this.id)" >Module 1 - Description of module
        <ul>
          <li id="1" onclick="alert(this.id)">Lesson 1: Description of lesson</li>
          <li id="2" onclick="alert(this.id)">Lesson 2: Description of lesson</li>
          <li id="3" onclick="alert(this.id)">Lesson 3: Description of lesson</li>
          <li id="4" onclick="alert(this.id)">Lesson 4: Description of lesson</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Module 2 - Description of module
        <ul>
          <li>Lesson 1: Description of lesson</li>
          <li>Lesson 2: Description of lesson</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Module 3 - Description of module
        <ul>
          <li>Lesson 1: Description of lesson</li>
          <li>Lesson 2: Description of lesson</li>
          <li>Lesson 3: Description of lesson</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Module 4 - Description of module
        <ul>
          <li>Lesson 1: Description of lesson</li>
          <li>Lesson 2: Description of lesson</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

i have this simple page of html. the thing is when I click on lesson1 i got two alerts showing 1 and 2 ??!!!
it's like i did click on both .in other words when i click on a sub`<li>` of another `<li>` (both have onclick event liestener) i get the javascript code runnig for both of them

Comment: I recommend to read the [quirksmode.org articles](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) to learn how event handlering works, especially the one about [event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `event.stopPropagation()` function to prevent the event from bubbling.

Here's a little example:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">123</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

document.querySelector('#div1').onclick = function()
    {
      alert('div1');  
    };

document.querySelector('#div2').onclick = function(event)
    {
      event.stopPropagation();
      alert('div2');  
    };
```

Comment: And what should they use in IE?

Comment: @FelixKling It's supported in IE9. For the older versions I'd recommend using a flag variable. So basically in the second event you set the flag as true. In the first event you check it and if it's true you reset it and don't execute the event handler

Comment: It's easier to set `event.cancelBubble = true;` IMHO. And you should mention in your answer that `stopPropagation` is not supported in IE<9.