# How to stop javascript bubbling of events?

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-bubbling

In my html code, I have a `td` tag that has an onclick event, and inside the `td` tag is an image tag that also has an onclick event. The problem is when I click the image, both its onclick and the td tag's onclick event occurs. How can I set it so that if I click the image tag, the td onclick event does not happen?

**Note: It should work with IE8 and higher.**

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli

Comment: Inside the onclick event for the image, use `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6203135/218196) provides a solution without jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the handler that shouldn't bubble:

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

*assuming your handler takes an event parameter of `e`*.

Comment: what if I have the code like: `<img onclick="alert(1)" src="..."/>`? How do I declare `e`?

Comment: Don't write code like that.

Comment: @omega: …and if you really needed, you could use the `event` variable which is available to inline event listeners

Comment: Note that this won't work in IE8 and below.

Comment: Oh forgot to mention, it needs to work in IE8 and higher.

Comment: @FelixKling I actually did not know that! Good note. [event.stopPropagation @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)

Comment: @omega: You should read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html and http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html.