# How to addEventListener only to body?

Tags: javascript

The code below will call the function on every element inside the body. But I only want it for body element.

```
const bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");

bodyElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("hello");
});
```

Comment: Every element lies inside body thats why this happens. So what is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to the event handler will be an [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

It has a [`target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) that will tell you the element clicked on.

Compare it to `bodyElement`.

Comment: For examples, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203112/924299) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815609/924299).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this:

```js
e.stopPropagation()
```

If I understand correctly, you want to use this only for one element, so...

Comment: "I only want [to call the function] for body element". So `stopPropagation` would need to be added for *every other* element, which doesn't seem efficient.